# Adding custom styles to foundation

Tags: css, npm, zurb-foundation-6

I'm building my first site with foundation. I installed foundation via npm. I believe it's good practice to leave the foundation styles alone and then overwrite what needs adjusting. The foundation styles would be included during the sass compile job (using gulp or whatever) as an external include. Is that the correct way?

The standard foundation installation (for sites) comes with lots of features I might not need. I'm worried about bloated css. How would I throw them out?

So the core question is - is it ok to mess with the foundation sources?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please don't change the core files, when you update foundation to a newer version you will lose al changes.

With sass version of foundation 6 you can choose what to output in your css. For example when using the foundation cli you have a app.scss file where they include all features. You can simply comment the features out you don't need in your project.

When you comment a feature out, you can still include styles with scss mixings.

App.scss

```
@charset 'utf-8';

@import 'settings';
@import 'foundation';
@import 'motion-ui';

@include foundation-global-styles;
@include foundation-grid;
// @include foundation-flex-grid;
@include foundation-typography;
@include foundation-button;
@include foundation-forms;
// @include foundation-range-input;
@include foundation-accordion;
@include foundation-accordion-menu;
@include foundation-badge;
@include foundation-breadcrumbs;
@include foundation-button-group;
@include foundation-callout;
@include foundation-close-button;
@include foundation-menu;
@include foundation-menu-icon;
@include foundation-drilldown-menu;
@include foundation-dropdown;
@include foundation-dropdown-menu;
@include foundation-flex-video;
@include foundation-label;
@include foundation-media-object;
@include foundation-off-canvas;
@include foundation-orbit;
@include foundation-pagination;
@include foundation-progress-bar;
// @include foundation-progress-element;
// @include foundation-meter-element;
@include foundation-slider;
@include foundation-sticky;
@include foundation-reveal;
@include foundation-switch;
@include foundation-table;
@include foundation-tabs;
@include foundation-thumbnail;
@include foundation-title-bar;
@include foundation-tooltip;
@include foundation-top-bar;
@include foundation-visibility-classes;
@include foundation-float-classes;
// @include foundation-flex-classes;

@include motion-ui-transitions;
@include motion-ui-animations;
```

Answer (score 0):

Editing **Core Files** is **not** a **good practice** so its better to create a custom stylesheet and including it below the foundation CSS.

Comment: I agree. I was just unsure since the foundation website lets you preconfigure your components and the root SCSS file just does a list of imports for these components. So I thought it was maybe ok to change that file since they do also? Or maybe not import the root SCSS and import the components myself directly?

Comment: Importing components manually is different from editing a core file. Changes made to the file will not create a problem as long as you don't come across a bug. Even while importing components you need to make sure everything is right or it will be a **time waste**.